# Cannot read property 'animateMarkerToCoordinate' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, native

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, Platform, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker, AnimatedRegion } from 'react-native-maps';
import PubNubReact from 'pubnub-react';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 37.78825;
const LONGITUDE = -122.4324;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

console.disableYellowBox = true;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: LATITUDE,
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
      coordinate: new AnimatedRegion({
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      }),
    };

    // Replace "X" with your PubNub Keys
    this.pubnub = new PubNubReact({
      publishKey: 'X',
      subscribeKey: 'X',
    });
    this.pubnub.init(this);
  }

  // code to receive messages sent in a channel
  componentDidMount() {
    this.subscribeToPubNub();
  }

  subscribeToPubNub = () => {
    this.pubnub.subscribe({
      channels: ['location'],
      withPresence: true,
    });
    this.pubnub.getMessage('location', msg => {
      const { coordinate } = this.state;
      const { latitude, longitude } = msg.message;
      const newCoordinate = { latitude, longitude };

      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        if (this.marker) {
          this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(newCoordinate, 500);
        }
      } else {
        coordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();
      }

      this.setState({
        latitude,
        longitude,
      });
    });
  };

  getMapRegion = () => ({
    latitude: this.state.latitude,
    longitude: this.state.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            showUserLocation
            followUserLocation
            loadingEnabled
            ref={c => (this.mapView = c)}
            region={this.state.latitude ? this.getMapRegion() : null}
          >
            <Marker.Animated
              ref={marker => {
                this.marker = marker;
              }}
              coordinate={this.state.coordinate}
            />
          </MapView>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

export default App;
```

I am getting error of **"Cannot read property 'animateMarkerToCoordinate' of undefined"**
in my React Native code. I am developing location tracking app on android. Which extracts LAT and LONG from another app and is want animate is on Google map. I read on some other sites that animateMarkerToCoordinate does not work in React Native for Android. Is it true? and If not what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2195#issuecomment-424246731

Comment: Yes i tried it but this code gives me this error.

Comment: Invariant Violation: [37,"AIRMapMarker",481,{"coordinate":{"latitude":37.78825,"longitude":-122.4324,"latitudeDelta":"<<NaN>>","longitudeDelta":"<<NaN>>"},"position":"absolute","backgroundColor":0}] is not usable as a native method argument

Comment: I am posting my complete code. So, anything is wrong in code please tell me

Comment: Yeah, because your `newCoordinate` object is missing the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`

Comment: @MatthewBenjamin I don't think this is the real issue as  this  issue comes in react native `0.63.1` version as in my pervious version code it is working fine as expected.  don't know the reason. btw I tested with adding both delta but not working in latest react native version.

Answer (score 1):

this issue came arise in react native `0.63.+` version. As per the official documentation of `react-native-maps`

```
 const duration = 500

  if (this.props.coordinate !== nextProps.coordinate) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      if (this.marker) {
        this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
          nextProps.coordinate,
          duration
        );
      }
    } else {
      this.state.coordinate.timing({
        ...nextProps.coordinate,
        duration
      }).start();
    }
  }
```

but this is not working with latest react-native version. just remove `_component` before `animateMarkerToCoordinate` it will work fine.

```
 const duration = 500

  if (this.props.coordinate !== nextProps.coordinate) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      if (this.marker) {
        this.marker.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
          nextProps.coordinate,
          duration
        );
      }
    } else {
      this.state.coordinate.timing({
        ...nextProps.coordinate,
        duration
      }).start();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In current versions of React Native and PubNub (4.31+), the message may not be obtained correctly using the `getMessage` method, and therefore the 'message' appears as `undefined`.

So if anyone has this problem, just use the `addListener` instead of `getMessage`, following their respective documentation.

I have spent days trying to run the same code and I hope I can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this GitHub answer: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2195#issuecomment-424246731 it would be best to just use the `coordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();` code.

```
Invariant Violation: [37,"AIRMapMarker",481,{"coordinate":{"latitude":37.78825,"longitude":-122.4324,"latitudeDelta":"<<NaN>>","longitudeDelta":"<<NaN>>"},"position":"absolute","backgroundColor":0}]
```

This failure is being caused because the `newCoordinate` is missing the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`, so the final code should look like this:

```
this.pubnub.getMessage('location', msg => {
      const { coordinate } = this.state;
      const { latitude, longitude } = msg.message;
      const newCoordinate = {
          latitude,
          longitude,
          latitudeDelta = LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta = LONGITUDE_DELTA
      };

      coordinate.timing(newCoordinate).start();

      this.setState({
        latitude,
        longitude,
      });
    });
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch. It will not crash

```
          if (this.marker && this.mounted) {

          setTimeout(() => {
            try {
              this.marker.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
                coordinate,
                duration
              )
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }

        }, 100);
        // this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
        //   coordinate,
        //   duration
        // );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

this.marker.animateMarkerToCoordinate use this instead of this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate